# Error during setup of own Airnotifier

Tags: android, mongodb, push-notification, moodle

In android phone, for push notification of my customized moodle app, I need to do setup of own Airnotfier server

I am following the instruction from [here](https://github.com/airnotifier/airnotifier/wiki/Installation) to install the Air Notifier, have installed all the requirements.

I run the below command under **setup AirNotifier** header

`python install.py`

But I got the following error, Shall I need to do something which is not mentioned on [tutorial](https://github.com/airnotifier/airnotifier/wiki/Installation).

[image]

How can I fix the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Is MongoDB running?

Use following guide to install and run MongoDB
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Comment: Installed `mongodb`, added ptyhon version 2.7.10, fixed problem produced by `python install.py`. 
Now started mongodb by `sudo service mongod start` it's all ok. Now start airnotifier server by `sudo python2.7 airnotifier.py >> airnotifier.log 2>> airnotifier.err`.
Found the error in log file
`File "airnotifier.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pymongo.connection import Connection
ImportError: No module named pymongo.connection`

Comment: I changed `airnotifer.conf` file, from `mongohost = "localhost"` to `mongohost = "127.0.0.1"`
Any suggestion on this error ?

Comment: pip install pymongo

Comment: mentioned `import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages')` in `airnotifier.py` file

Comment: When I start the airNotifier server by `sudo python2.7 airnotifier.py >> airnotifier.log 2>> airnotifier.err'` Following error would come
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "airnotifier.py", line 288, in <module>
    AirNotifierApp(services=services).main()
  File "airnotifier.py", line 197, in main
    ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain(options.httpscertfile, options.httpskeyfile)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`